# Prestashop 1.6 - Access denied on backoffice custom module after modification

Tags: controller, http-status-code-403, prestashop-1.6

for the first time, i work on existent custom modules developed by old web developer on prestashop 1.6.
My problem is about a custom module used to manage status for new publications.
I work on two controllers class in /controller/admin who manage two admin views.

I have done some modifications on second view controller without any problems (add / manage customs field on form or tab).
But in the first admin controller, as soon as I process to modification in postProcess() function,
I have a "access denied" on the module view in backoffice.

I've verified acces rights on tab and permissions/employees, access right on ftp files, i didn't see any problem. I am super admin.

Is there something to do after modifying custom module file to access to its view in backoffice ?
This module has many tabs / views and others don't have this issue.

It's the first time i work on existent custom modules, and i didn't find anything on documentation or others posts.

Please help me, any advises are welcome.

I didn't change any .tpl files. Just the custom module/controller/admin file.
I try to clear cache manually.
When I put back the old controller file, everything work fine.
I verify access / permissions / roles on BDD for module tabs and everything is ok.

EDIT : issue doesn't occurs on another server containing same file for another website. (same project architecture)
I think the problem is based on server settings or WAF.

EDIT 2 : After resolve WAF settings, my php file displaying in plain text. My web hosting has confirmed everything is fine in apache conf.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.